MacOS Python3 venv: ".so" file is missing in installed dependency, resulting to "ModuleNotFound"
I need fastpbkdf2 dependency. I have created the virtual environment with python3 -m venv and run pip install fastpbkdf2. When I'm trying to run tests with pytest, having all dependencies installed without errors, I receive the error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastpbkdf2._fastpbkdf2'. As I've figured out, the reason is missing file: .venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastpbkdf2/_fastpbkdf2.abi3.so. However, when I install this dependency globally or through the Docker container, the file is present without extra actions. Building the dependency locally resolves the issue, but this doesn't sound like a normal flow. IDK where to open an issue, that's why asking here.
Steps to reproduce
Prerequisites

Python 3.12 (also reproduced on Python 3.10)
MacOS 14.5
Pip 24.0

Flow

Install fuzzy extractor repo:

git clone git@github.com:carter-yagemann/python-fuzzy-extractor.git
cd python-fuzzy-extractor


Init and activate venv:

python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate


Install requirements:

pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.testing.txt


Try to run tests: python3 -m pytest

Results
I get the error:
ImportError while importing test module '/path/to/project/tests/fuzzy_extractor_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py:90: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
tests/fuzzy_extractor_test.py:26: in <module>
    from fuzzy_extractor import FuzzyExtractor
fuzzy_extractor/__init__.py:35: in <module>
    from fastpbkdf2 import pbkdf2_hmac
.venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastpbkdf2/__init__.py:7: in <module>
    from fastpbkdf2._fastpbkdf2 import ffi, lib
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastpbkdf2._fastpbkdf2'

If you run ls .venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/fastpbkdf2, you will see that .so file is absent.
You may try the same commands in Dockerfile and find out that the file _fastpbkdf2.abi3.so exists.
The current solution is to build extension in fastpbkdf2 and install it:
# ensure that your .venv is in fuzzy-extractor or another desired project
git clone https://github.com/Ayrx/python-fastpbkdf2.git
cd python-fastpbkdf2
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
python3 setup.py install


https://pypi.org/project/fastpbkdf2/ Last version 0.2 released in 2016. https://github.com/Ayrx/python-fastpbkdf2 Archived by the owner in 2021. The package seems to be old and abandoned. Are you sure you really want to use it?

Well, I just want to use the library which depends on this package. And migration to the different package is not the case now. Just curious what's broken.
